# Molecular simulator, JavaFX

Tags: multithreading, javafx, updates

I'm hoping to make a big and effective molecular simulator, but I'm having a problem. 
When I add molecules or atoms to the javaFX screen, they update their position and once in a while some of the atoms disappear, because their old positions did not update the way they should.

The only way they update, is that in each frame(step), they start by updating the old position to what the current position was last frame(step). And this is the error, sometimes it updates to x,y,z = 0,0,0. Even though it should have been 421,225,14 etc.

The old positions are always updated to 0,0,0, when the error occurs.

I use 4 threads to run the program, with thread safe lists, that are not divided between the threads, that is, each thread has 1/4 of the screen to process.

This is the update method:

```
private void updateOldPositions() {
    lastXPos = xPos;
    lastYPos = yPos;
    lastZPos = zPos;
}
```

This method is then not working, so the program adds infinite amounts of the same molecule, because it cant find the old positions of the molecule to remove. 
They are all now x,y,z = 0,0,0.

```
cellLists.get((a.getLastXPos()+a.getLastYPos()+a.getLastZPos())/d).remove(a);
```

Anyone got an idea for what the problem is, can add link to git hub if you need to see more of the code. Thank you.

Comment: `cellLists.get((a.getLastXPos()+a.getLastYPos()+a.getLastZPos())/d).remove(a);` This looks odd to me. The lists' get method usually expects an index argument and here it is computed from coordinates ? What if two cells have the same computed index ? Btw, you should expose more code if you want help, the `updateOldPositions()` method just tells nothing.

Comment: The reason for the coordinates is to remove the condition that all atoms must check all other atoms in the scene for colitions, which can be several billion.
See this: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_lists
 And yes, some atoms far away will be in same list, i.g 
x = 5,y = 121,z = 521 and   x = 521, y = 121, z = 5. Which are faaar way from eachother, and should not be in same list. 
Do you have a better idea for that ?